# Error: I got an error compiling scss to css, while my scripts command entered the correct directory name and file name

Tags: css, npm, sass, node-sass

Error cmd notice [image: Error cdm notice]

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Looking forward to everyone's help, I'm learning sass but when I install it on npm, I get an error compiling scss to css, while my scripts enter the correct directory and file names

This is my folder structure:
[image: This is my folder structure]

Comment: Did you try to rename the directory name "New" by "new" ? Or try to write your path with "\" instead of "/" in your cmd call ?

Comment: thank you, but it still doesn't work for you

Comment: You tried both ? and still same error ? `-o` is missing in your compile:sass way in package.json

Comment: yes, i tried both, but still not working

Comment: > new-folder@1.0.0 compile:sass
> node-sass Sass/main.scss -o Style/style.css -w

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: node-sass is deprecated. Maybe using sass would be more straightforward? https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass